# Why does ReplaceAll change the ordering of expresssions?

Tags: replacement, attributes

I wrote the following replacing statement:

```
Binomial[12 - u - v - w + z,  4 - u - w + z] /. 
  {u -> Subscript[c, αβ], 
   v -> Subscript[c, βγ], w -> Subscript[c, γα], 
   z -> Subscript[c, αβγ]}
```

which on the screen is displayed as

$$\text{Binomial}[12 - u - v - w + z,\ 4 - u - w + z]\ /.\{u\rightarrow c_{\alpha\beta},\ v\rightarrow c_{\beta\gamma},\ w\rightarrow c_{\gamma\alpha},\ z\rightarrow c_{\alpha\beta\gamma}\}$$

But the result is

```
Binomial[
  12 - Subscript[c, αβ] + Subscript[ c, αβγ] - Subscript[c, β[Gamma]] - 
  Subscript[c, γα], 4 - Subscript[c, αβ] + Subscript[ c, αβγ] - Subscript[c, γα]]
```

which on the screen is displayed as

$$\text{Binomial}[12 - c_{\alpha\beta}+c_{\alpha\beta\gamma} - c_{\beta\gamma} - c_{\gamma\alpha} ,\,4 - c_{\alpha\beta}+ c_{\alpha\beta\gamma} -c_{\gamma\alpha} ]$$

from which we see the ordering of $u,v,w,z$ are shuffled after `ReplaceAll`, and with the original ordering it would have been

$$\text{Binomial}[12 - c_{\alpha\beta} - c_{\beta\gamma} - c_{\gamma\alpha}+c_{\alpha\beta\gamma}, \,4 - c_{\alpha\beta} -c_{\gamma\alpha}+ c_{\alpha\beta\gamma} ]$$

Why is this shuffling happening and how can I prevent it?

Comment: `Plus[]` is commutative (has the `Orderless` attribute), so *Mathematica* will sort addends in a canonical order.

Comment: @J.M. thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not an effect of `Replace`. It is caused by `Plus` having the attribute [`Orderless`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Orderless.html), which makes it act as a Abelian operator. If further computation is not needed, you can suppress the reordering with `HoldForm`.

```
HoldForm @ 
  Binomial[
    12 - Subscript[c, αβ] + Subscript[c, αβγ] - Subscript[c, β[Gamma]] - 
      Subscript[c, γα], 
    4 - Subscript[c, αβ] + Subscript[c, αβγ] - Subscript[c, γα]]
```

[image: held_form]

Comment: I see, thank you!